# Wordpress Forget password link is not Work

Tags: wordpress

I want reset my pwd but it give me error 404.
I move my mouse on the forget pwd link and I get this link: **https://site_url/profil/?a=pwdreset**

Where i can modify this **"/?a=pwdreset"** link ?
I use rocketgeek wp-members.

Answer (score 0):

Hey man look this link

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/change-url-in-password-reset-email/

I believe it can help you I already changed the link using a plugin but I believe that nowadays there are others. But there is this solution too

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/161908/how-to-change-rewrite-the-lost-password-url

Answer (score -1):

hey man do you see your htaccess? Maybe your problem are on htaccess and permissions at your folder.

Comment: thanks for answer.
in my htacces i have /wp-content/plugins/wp-members/$1 [L,QSA] and so many lignes like this.
but in my url https://site_url/profil/?a=pwdreset, the profil page is empty and not use it for reset password where i can change the link ?